# VBA Error 1004 - No cell was found, how to solve?

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run a macro to fill empty cells, using a filter to fill only the desired cells, I get error 1004, with the message that no cell was found

Error line:

```
Sheets(sheets(k)).Range(columns(j) & rows(i) & ":" & columns(j) & row_number_1).Select
      ''Error Line""         
      **Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select**
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "P
```

I changed the formulas, referencing the object directly, but the macro fills unwanted cells, and even overlaps others that already have values ​​inside

Comment: Sometimes what you think are blank cells are not really blank - they may contain formulas, or empty strings. For instance `=IF(A1>"100", "x", "")` - this cell may have an empty string in it.

Comment: Note: you need to clean up your code (it seems incomplete and a little garbled). Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please share the complete code and a decent description of what it does and of what it is supposed to do. It is hard to believe that the code could survive the first row of your snippet so whatever you are doing before it, is at least incorrect if not worse.

Comment: Also if a cell is outside of the `Sheet.UsedRange`, it will not be part of `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, even though it may look blank

Answer (score 0):

- There is no need to explicitly select a range before setting a formula, selecting range can actually cause errors if the result of SpecialCells is nothing.
- There is a simple way to reference a range if i, j were row / column index. Of course, your approach might get the same result.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim rData As Range
    With Sheets(k)
        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(row_number_1, j)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Not rData Is Nothing Then rData.FormulaR1C1 = "P"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Think about the following preceding code: `Dim sheets(): sheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"): Dim rows(): rows = Array(1, 2, 3, 4): Dim columns(): columns = Array("A", "C", "G")`. It is 'blasphemy' but now the first line (*"the range reference code line"*) works.

Comment: @VBasic2008. You are right. All roads lead to Rome.